MouseDown event
Consider this code:
DynamicModule[{cnt = 0},Dynamic@EventHandler[Dynamic[cnt], "MouseDown":> (While[CurrentValue["MouseButtons"] == {1},cnt++])]]

I want it to display the continuously changing value of "cnt" as the mouse is pressed. This code only displays the last value as the button is released. How to modify this to make it work as desired?
Thanks

Please add that you've simultaneously posted at https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3232045.  Otherwise if an answer is posted there, you'd be wasting time for the folks at this site.

Your approach is not working, because upon clicking, the code gets "stuck" in While loop. Instead, I suggest you add a new variable that indicates whether the current state is clicked or not.
DynamicModule[{cnt = 0, clicked = False}, 
 EventHandler[Dynamic[If[clicked, cnt++, cnt]], 
   {"MouseDown" :> (clicked = True), 
    "MouseUp" :> (clicked = False)}]]


Thanks for the neat solution Domen.
